# Philosophy of beauty / Science

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, beauty

I have been thinking about the idea of science and its rightful activity conveying beauty. I got this idea from a quote from Richard P. Feynman which I attach it in the end of my question for clarification.

I would like to ask you if you know any author covering these topics OR if you can recommend me books/authors. I am a trained evolutionary biology who loves philosophy so I would be happy to learn more about these topics.

> I have a friend who's an artist and has sometimes taken a view which I don't agree with very well. He'll hold up a flower and say "look how beautiful it is," and I'll agree. Then he says "I as an artist can see how beautiful this is but you as a scientist take this all apart and it becomes a dull thing," and I think that he's kind of nutty. First of all, the beauty that he sees is available to other people and to me too, I believe. Although I may not be quite as refined aesthetically as he is ... I can appreciate the beauty of a flower. At the same time, I see much more about the flower than he sees. I could imagine the cells in there, the complicated actions inside, which also have a beauty. I mean it's not just beauty at this dimension, at one centimeter; there's also beauty at smaller dimensions, the inner structure, also the processes. The fact that the colors in the flower evolved in order to attract insects to pollinate it is interesting; it means that insects can see the color. It adds a question: does this aesthetic sense also exist in the lower forms? Why is it aesthetic? All kinds of interesting questions which the science knowledge only adds to the excitement, the mystery and the awe of a flower. It only adds. I don't understand how it subtracts. (Richard P. Feynman)

Comment: A source of the quote would be nice.

Comment: Hi Philip - I found it on his book "Surely you're joking Mr. Feyman". I loved reading this book. But I believe the original citation was given in an interview to BBC - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSZNsIFID28

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the series of interviews Wim Kayzer did for the Dutch VPRO, titled "Beauty and Consolation". He interviewed philosophers, scientists and artists, they speak about their reflections on the subject, approaching the subject from their respective field. Each interview lasts about two hours.

The interview with physicist Edward Witten might be an interesting starting point. (He also interviewed Roger Scruton.)